# Count distinct rows where another column not the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how to do a count on NUM, where CODE is not distinct?

So the count would be Two!?

```
CODE    NUM
T1  1001
T1  1001
T1  1001
T2  1002
T2  1002
T3  1003
T3  1003
T4  1003
T5  1004
T5  1004
T5  1004
T6  1005
T7  1005
T7  1005
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What is your expected result..?

Comment: Please don't use code snippets unless there is an actual code snippet in there. There are other options for formatting the question...

Comment: @Ullas The answer I was looking for was 2, I included my expected result.

Comment: @GIS_USER - ***how to do a count on NUM,  where CODE is not distinct*** - how is the accepted answer does that. Do us all a favour and add expected output in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Try Below code :

 SELECT NUM , COUNT(*)
 FROM #table
 GROUP BY NUM
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) > 1
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select count(*)
From (
  Select num
  From t
  Group by num
  Having count(distinct code) > 1
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create table #Tempt
(
    CODE varchar(50), 
    NUM int

)

Delete From #Tempt

 insert into #Tempt Values('T1',1001)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T1',1001)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T1',1001)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T2',1002)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T2',1002)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T2',1002)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T3',1003)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T3',1003)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T4',1004)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T5',1005)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T5',1005)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T6',1006)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T7',1007)
 insert into #Tempt Values('T7',1007) 

Select Count(*) as TotalCount From (Select Code,Num ,
(Select Count(*) From #Tempt Where code = t.code) as CountCode 
from #Tempt as t) as v Where CountCode=1
```